# How to tell chmod to follow symbolic links?

Tags: debian, chmod

`chown` has an option `-L` which tells `chown` to traverse symbolic links. It seems this option is missing for `chmod`. Any idea how to tell `chmod` to follow symlinks as well?

EDIT: I'm on Debian.

Comment: You should mention that it's Linux or some other system. I was confused because FreeBSD has got `-L` for both commands.

Comment: true, I'm on Debian.

Answer (score 12):

For Linux/GNU see the second paragraph of the info page [also on the Web](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html#chmod-invocation), emphasis added:

> chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links, since the chmod system call cannot change their permissions. This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used. However, **for each symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions of the pointed-to file**. In contrast, chmod ignores symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals.

Comment: Okay so chmod ignores symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals. So chmod is not capable of it. So propably I have to use `find -L` in combination of `chmod`.